# Почему может не работать парсер авито?

Tags: python, csv, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

При запуске кода через консоль windows x64 выскакивает ошибка:
https://ibb.co/mTYLvtq

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема, буду благодарен)

Код вот он:

```
import requests
import csv

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# План:
# 1) Выяснить количество страниц
# 2) Сформировать список урлов на страницы выдачи
# 3) Собрать данные

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text


def get_total_pages(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    pages = soup.find('div', class_='pagination-pages').find_all('a', 
class_='pagination-page')
    total_pages = pages.split('=')[1].split('&')[0]

    return imt(total_pages)


def write_csv(data):
    with open('avito.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)

        writer.writerow(
                        (
                            data['title'],
                            data['price'],
                            data['metro'],
                            data['url']))


def get_page_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    ads = soup.find('div', class_='catalog-list').find_all('div', 
class_='item_table')

    for ad in abs:
        # title, price, metro, url
        try:
            title = ad.find('div', 
class_='description').find('h3').text.strip()
        except:
            title = ''
        try:
            url = ad.find('div', 
class_='description').find('h3').find('a').get('href')
        except:
            url = ''
        try:
            price = ad.find('div', class_='about').text.strip()
        except:
            price = ''
        try:
            metro = ad.find('div', class_='data').find_all('p') 
[-1].text.strip()
        except:
             metro = ''
        data = {'title': title,
                'price': price,
                'metro': metro,
                'url': url}
        write_csv(data)


def main():
    url = 'https://www.avito.ru/moskva/telefony?p=1&q=htc'
    base_url = 'https://www.avito.ru/moskva/telefony?'
    page_part = 'p='
    query_part = '&q=htc'

    total_pages = get_total_pages(get_html(url))

    for i in range(1, 3):
        url_gen = base_url + page_part + str(i) + query_part
        html = get_html(url_gen)
        get_page_data(html)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все написано в сообщении об ошибке. После выполнения

```
pages = soup.find('div', class_='pagination-pages').find_all('a', class_='pagination-page')
```

переменная `pages` содержит набор найденных элементов. Вы же обращаетесь с ним как со строкой, применяя метод `split()` - `pages.split('=')`
Если вы хотите обработать каждый элемент, то нужно пройтись по этому набору:

```
for page in pages:
    # в теле цикла работаем с каждым отдельным элементом
```

или обратиться к конкретному элементу по индексу, например: `pages[0]`

Comment: А если по проще?

Comment: @НикитаКотов строка не равно список, достаточно просто? Pages - это список, а split применяется только к строкам, чтобы перебрать все элементы списка нужно использовать цикл for